# Quick Select Algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, quickselect

I'm trying to implement the Quick Select Algorithm on an array that has randomly generated numbers. Now after coding the algorithm, it does not sort the array from lowest to highest nor am I able to find the *k*th smallest element.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int Partition(int *myArray, int startingIndex, int endingIndex){
    int pivot = myArray[endingIndex];
    int partitionIndex = startingIndex;
    for(int i = startingIndex; i<endingIndex; i++){
        if(myArray[i]<= pivot){
            swap(myArray[i],myArray[partitionIndex]);
            partitionIndex++;
        }
    }
    swap(myArray[partitionIndex],myArray[endingIndex]);
    return partitionIndex;
} 
 
int QuickSelect(int *myArray, int startingIndex, int endingIndex, int KthElement){
    if (startingIndex < endingIndex){
        int partitionIndex = Partition(myArray, startingIndex, endingIndex);
        if(KthElement == partitionIndex)
            return KthElement;
        if(KthElement < partitionIndex)
            QuickSelect(myArray, startingIndex, partitionIndex - 1, KthElement);
        else
            QuickSelect(myArray, partitionIndex + 1, endingIndex, KthElement);
    }
}
    /*if(startingIndex < endingIndex){
        int partitionIndex = Partition(myArray, startingIndex,endingIndex);
        QuickSelect(myArray,startingIndex,partitionIndex-1);
        QuickSelect(myArray,partitionIndex+1,endingIndex);
    }// 1 */

void printArray(string intro, int const *myArray, int n, ostream &out) {
    out << intro;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        out << " " << myArray[i];
    }
    out << endl;
}

int main(){
    int numOfElements;
    int KthElement;
    srand(time(NULL));
    cout<<"Enter The Amount Of Numbers You Wish To Use: ";
    cin >> numOfElements;
    int myArray[numOfElements];

    for(int i = 0; i< numOfElements; i++){
        myArray[i] = rand() %10;
    }

    printArray("Array Before Sorting:", myArray, numOfElements, cout);

    cout <<"\nEnter The Rank K Of The Element You Wish To Retrieve: ";
    cin >> KthElement;

    QuickSelect(myArray,0,numOfElements,KthElement);

    printArray("Array After Sorting:", myArray, numOfElements, cout);

    cout << "The " << KthElement << " Smallest Element Is: "
         << QuickSelect(myArray,0,numOfElements,KthElement);
}
```

Comment: Just a small reminder, the quick select algorithm will NOT sort your array.

Comment: The QuickSelect algorithm does not sort the entire array. That's not what it's for. That's how it differs from QuickSort, which does.

Answer (score 2):

For `numOfElements` as 5, array extends from 0 to 4.
Your `endingIndex` assumes that its the last index of the array.

Fix:

```
QuickSelect(myArray, 0,numOfElements-1,KthElement);
```

Problems with your code:

- Your program accesses out of bound array locations in

  ```
  int pivot = myArray[endingIndex];
  ```
- Have a check for `k<1` and `k>(num_of_elements)`.
- Check your code for num_of_elements = 1 as well.
- Check what k means for the array, i.e For `k=1` , `arr[0]` should be returned not `arr[1]`;

Answer (score 0):

Problems with your `int QuickSelect()`:
• not documented - what does it return, why `KthElement` and not `k`?
• does not always return a value
• where it *does* return a value, it is always the unmodified value of its last parameter